# Compare Enum DisplayName to string in search

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, enums

I have an Enum values that I also use "displayname" and I would like to pass it as parameter to a search, what I did so far is:

```
public enum Gender
{
    [Display(Name = "Man & Weman")]
    EvryOne = 0,
    [Display(Name = "Man")]
    Man = 1,
    //Etc...
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string GetEnumDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
    {
        return enumValue.GetType()
                        .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
                        .First()
                        .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>()
                        .GetName();
    }


    public ActionResult EventsList(string query = null)
    {

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query))
        {
            query = query.Trim();
            upCommingLecture = upCommingLecture
                .Where(g =>
                    g.Address.Contains(query) ||
                    Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Gender), query) ||
                    //Etc...
        }
    }
}
```

The action link I'm using:

```
@Html.ActionLink("#ISFor  " +
    @Model.LectureGig.Gender.GetEnumDisplayName() +" "+ "|", "EventsList", "Events", new
      {
          @query = Model.LectureGig.Gender.GetEnumDisplayName()
      }, null)
```

The error I get is:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean IsDefined(System.Type, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

So what I need to do is to compare the value from `GetEnumDisplayName` to the `GetEnumDisplayName` in my Enum list. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should perform `Enum.IsDefined` outside the query and pass it to the query using a Boolean field/property, since `IsDefined` method can't be translated to equivalent SQL query.

Comment: i'm not sure i knowhow, i did bool gander = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Gender), query); ,but how to use it in the Where ?

Comment: Try changing `IsDefined` method with your `bool` field: `upCommingLecture = upCommingLecture.Where(g => g.Address.Contains(query) || gander || // etc );`. It should generate proper SQL query to be passed in LINQ to Entities.